# Ocaml: Error - this expression has type x but is used with type x

Tags: ocaml, tuareg

This is my error:

```
Error: This expression has type nfa but is here used with type nfa
```

What could possibly be happening to cause this? I'm using emacs tuareg, and loading evaluating files one by one. Sometimes this happens, and other times it doesn't.

Comment: can you post the code that generates this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a good description of this in the [ocaml tutorial](http://www.ocaml-tutorial.org/common_error_messages). What's happened is you have shadowed a type definition with a new definition:

```
type nfa = int
let f (x: nfa) = x

type nfa = int
let g (x: nfa) = x
```

Restarting the top-level will clear out the old definitions.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Since OCaml 4.01.0 (released Sept. 2013) the general problem is the same, but the error message adds a number to the type definition, to make evident the types are internally different.

Full example from the [old OCaml FAQ](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/FAQ_EXPERT-eng.html#message_incomprehensible) in the *toplevel*:

```
type counter = Counter of int;; (* define a type *)
type counter = Counter of int
# let x = Counter 1;;           (* use the new type *)
val x : counter = Counter 1
type counter = Counter of int;; (* redefine the type, use it *)
type counter = Counter of int
# let incr_counter c = match c with Counter x -> Counter (x + 1);;
val incr_counter : counter -> counter = <fun>
# incr_counter x;;              (* now mix old and new defs *)
Error: This expression has type counter/1029
       but an expression was expected of type counter/1032
#
```